# Play/Pause button not updating in lockscreen always it will show pause button in Swift4 ios

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a Audio player that can play from the iOS command center and lock screen. When I toggle a play/pause button in my app, it should update the play/pause button in the command center (MPRemoteCommandCenter) by updating the nowPlayingInfo (MPNowPlayingInfoCenter). But it's not updating.

But when i try to control from lockscreen Play/Pause its updating in my app toggle buttons this works fine.But similarly when i am controlling from inside my app play/pause button. its not updating play/pause button in lockscreen.Always its show pause button.

Iam setting Playbackrate 1.0 for play and 0.0 for pause.But still its not updating..

Can some please give me any suggestions or anything missing in this below code.

```
   func setupLockScreenDisplay() {
        var nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = self.currentSongName
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = self.currentAlbum == nil ? self.totalDurationTime : playerItem.asset.duration.seconds
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = isPlaying ? 1.0 : 0.0
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyMediaType] = NSNumber(value: MPNowPlayingInfoMediaType.audio.rawValue)
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = self.currentAlbum == nil ? self.storyPlayer.currentTime : CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
        // Set the metadata
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState = .playing
    }
```

below code for remote command below code is working fine..i can able to control from lockscreen

```
func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.play()
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.pause()
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.nextPlay()
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.lastPlay()
            return .success
        }
        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true
    }
```

Here code for inside play button

```
func play() {
        if self.currentAlbum == nil {
            self.storyPlayer.play()
        } else {
            self.player.play()
        }
        self.isPlaying = true
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: kPlayerManagerChangePlayingStateRsp), object: nil)
        setupLockScreenDisplay()
        setupRemoteCommandCenter()
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo![MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 1
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo![MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    }
```

code inside pause button

```
func pause() {
        if self.currentAlbum == nil {
            self.storyPlayer.pause()
        } else {
            self.player.pause()
        }
        self.isPlaying = false
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: kPlayerManagerChangePlayingStateRsp), object: nil)
        setupLockScreenDisplay()
        setupRemoteCommandCenter()
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo![MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo![MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your view did load func or app delegate

```
do {
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
     print("Playback OK")
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
     print("Session is Active")
   } 
   catch {
     print(error)
   }
```

and on your background modes in capabilities.

[image: 1]